# OmniFaces methodParam check null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, tagfile

Is there any way to know if the action has value?
I have two buttons on my component(custom-tag) . If I fill out the " actionRemove " parameter the Remove button appears. (`rendered="#{not empty actionRemove}"`)

Primefaces: 5.0, Jsf: 2.2, Omnifaces: 2.0